# Выборка из таблицы с условием

Tags: mysql

Есть табличка `products`, и в ней колонки `price`, `new_price`, `stock` и `id_product`.
Выглядит это примерно так:

```
price    new_price    stock    id_product
45.50      41.87        1          25
78.99      <null>       0          14
89.15      56.89        1          67
34.11      <null>       0          48
23.56      <null>       0          55
```

Нужно выбрать цены по `id_product`: если `stock = 1`, то выбирать `new_price`, а если `stock = 0`, то выбирать `price`. И задать какой-то alias типа `alias_price`, чтобы в массиве потом цены были под одним названием, а не одни `price`, другие `new_price`. Что-то не получается у меня сделать такую выборку...

Comment: `select if(stock = 1, new_price, price) alias_price ...`

Comment: хотя если new_price действительно null во всех случаях, когда stock=0, то достаточно `coalesce(new_price,price)`

Comment: new_price действительно null во всех случаях, когда stock=0

Comment: @Mike, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ответом. ТС, [так надо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35280a/1)?

Comment: да, всё отлично работает, сэнкс за помощь